# Retrieve device information in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How i can retrieve information about installed devices in windows phone (e.g. gps, bluetooth, accelerometer)?

In windows mobile I can use Status or SystemState class. And what about Windows Phone?

I'm beginner with this technology, and I have to do this for university.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Device Status sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29) which can guide you through using the [Devicesstatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus%28v=vs.92%29) class which can be used to query for the presence of a keyboards and other optional hardware components -- [it is my understanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637514%28v=vs.92%29) that a location sensor (GPS or otherwise), bluetooth and possibly the accelerometer are all part of the minimum hardware specification so these are not reported via this API (as there is nothing to query)

Comment: I tried this before I asked question here. I this you're right - gps, bluetooth or accelerometer are minimum for WP, and there is no possibility to get info about these devices.